# convert a date format yyyy-mm-dd in sqllite

Tags: android, sqlite

need a date format like this in sqllite`2013-10-29`

my query was `SELECT strftime('%Y-%m-%d', '29/10/2013')`

but it showing blank output.I don't know what is the problem.

**MY ANS FOR DAY DIFF**

=================================

```
SELECT cast(julianday() - julianday((substr(date_time,7,4) || '-' ||  substr(date_time,4,2) || '-' || substr(date_time,0,3)))as integer) as DayDiff  from sms_table
```

Comment: instead of using `SELECT strftime('%Y-%m-%d', '29/10/2013')` try using `SELECT strftime('%Y-%m-%d', '2013/10/29')`

Comment: I am getting this `29/10/2013` from database so how can I modify to `2013/10/29`

Comment: If you need to get the current date then you can use this `SELECT date('now');`

Comment: Please try to understand I am not dealing with date('now') I need a date from data base which have a format like `29/10/2013`

Comment: Please check this link it might help you : http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_date_time.htm

Comment: I already goes through that. It was not helpful

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html), the second argument of `strftime` is meant to be a `timestring`, which need to be in one of the following formats:

> - *YYYY-MM-DD*
> - *YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM*
> - *YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS*
> - *YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS*
> - *YYYY-MM-DD***T***HH:MM*
> - *YYYY-MM-DD***T***HH:MM:SS*
> - *YYYY-MM-DD***T***HH:MM:SS.SSS*
> - *HH:MM*
> - *HH:MM:SS*
> - *HH:MM:SS.SSS*
> - **now**
> - *DDDDDDDDDD*

Your slash-separated string is non of these, so it can't be parsed.

I suggest you change the format before inserting the data into your database in the first place (assuming your query would normally be running over your data).

If you can't do that, you'll quite possibly need to use string manipulation either to convert straight to your preferred format, or into one of the above forms so that you can *then* use `strftime`.

Comment: is it possible to replace all `/` to `-` before conversion

Comment: @bumba: You could use the `replace` function - but as I said before, why not fix the data to be appropriate for Sqlite before you even insert it?

Comment: When I replace this query with this `select strftime('%Y-%m-%d', replace( '29/10/2013', '/', '-')) ` still no result

Comment: @bumba: Well 29/10/2013 with the spaces replaced would give 29-10-2013. Which of the formats listed in my answer does that correspond to? Yet again, I strongly recommend that you insert the data in a more useful format to start with. Why do you keep ignoring that suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

If you can't control date string supplied to database, you can manipulate submitted date as this:

```
SELECT
    REPLACE(SUBSTR(d, CASE SUBSTR(d, 6, 1) WHEN '/' THEN 7 ELSE 5 END), '/', '')||'-'|| --Year
    SUBSTR('0'||REPLACE(SUBSTR(d, 3, CASE SUBSTR(d, 4, 1) WHEN '/' THEN 2 ELSE 3 END), '/', ''), -2)||'-'|| --Month
    SUBSTR('0'||REPLACE(SUBSTR(d, 1, 2), '/', ''), -2) --Day
FROM (SELECT '11/11/2013' AS d);
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert the date into milliseconds and then use

```
SELECT strftime("%Y-%m-%d", 1384108200000/1000 , 'unixepoch').
```

This is one of the ways to use strftime

Comment: how can I convert it to milisec dynamically

Comment: If you are creating the table..just create date field as Long type and store date value in milliseconds. If you follow this method you can convert to any form. If you dont have access to change the table then this solution is not useful.

Answer (score 0):

As described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19151304/19679), you can convert date into milliseconds and then use:

```
String someDate = "1995-01-01";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date date = sdf.parse(someDate);
System.out.println(date.getTime());
```

Comment: I need a single line query for SQLLITE datase.

Answer (score -1):

Answer may not work with Android  --  generally, If original date looks like `mm/dd/yyyy` and desired format is yyyy-mm-dd, then easily change each row with:

**update tableName set claimDate = substr(claimDate,7) || '-' || substr(claimDate,1,2) || '-' || substr(claimDate,4,2)**

or to just select

**select substr(claimDate,7) || '-' || substr(claimDate,1,2) || '-' || substr(claimDate,4,2) from tableName**

`claimDate` is field in `tableName`